# How to convert a Seq of Tuple2s of Tuple2s to a Tuple2 of Maps

Tags: scala, tuples

I have a sequence of data that I want to convert into a pair of maps; each map represents a separate transformation of the original sequence. I can generate tuples that will make up each map in a single pass over the original input sequence as follows:

```
val entries: Seq[((A, B), (A, C))] = input map { x =>
  val key = genKey(x)
  val tuple1 = key -> f(x)
  val tuple2 = key -> g(x)
}
```

I could create each map individually by traversing the resulting seq twice, like so:

```
val map1 = (entries map { case(e1, _) => e1 }).toMap
val map2 = (entries map { case(_, e2) => e2 }).toMap
```

I presume there is probably a way to do the whole transformation in a single pass over the map, so that I could do something like this:

```
val (map1, map2) = (entries accumulate { case(e1, e2) => // add e1 to map1, add e2 to map2 })
```

A foldLeft would probably do it, but maybe there's something more elegant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the standard library:

```
val (map1, map2) = entries.unzip match {
  case (pairs1, pairs2) => (pairs1.toMap, pairs2.toMap)
}
```

With [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) its a one-liner:

```
val (map1, map2) = entries.unzip.bimap(_.toMap, _.toMap)
```

Both of these solutions will create two extra intermediate sequences, though. This probably isn't something you need to worry about, but if you really want to avoid it, the fold actually isn't that inelegant at all:

```
val (map1, map2) = entries.foldLeft(Map.empty[A, B], Map.empty[A, C]) {
  case ((map1, map2), (pair1, pair2)) => (map1 + pair1, map2 + pair2)
}
```

No Scalaz required.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your `entries` method above, then the obvious way is:

```
val (s1, s2) = entries.unzip
val map1 = s1.toMap
val map2 = s2.toMap
```

However you're still (1) traversing your `inputs` to create a seqence of tuples, then (2) traversing again in the `unzip`, then (3) traversing in `s1.toMap`, and (4) again in `s2.toMap`.

If your concern is minimal traversals, as your question implies, you need to build the results manually. Elegant, no, but straightforward, and you can do away with your `entries` method.

```
val (map1, map2) = {
  val b1, b2 = Map.newBuilder[Int, String]
  input foreach { i =>
    val k = genKey(i)
    b1 += k -> f(i)
    b2 += k -> g(i)
  }
  (b1.result, b2.result)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this would be my approach (imho easier to grasp for beginners):

```
object TupleTest {

  def transform[A, B, C](entries: Seq[((A, B), (A, C))]): (Map[A, B], Map[A, C]) =
    {

      def acc[A, B, C](entries: Seq[((A, B), (A, C))], map1: Map[A, B], map2: Map[A, C]): (Map[A, B], Map[A, C]) =
        {
          entries match {
            case Nil => (map1, map2)
            case hd :: tl => acc(tl, map1.+(hd._1), map2.+(hd._2))
          }

        }
      acc(entries, Map.empty[A, B], Map.empty[A, C])

    }

}
```